# Coupon code Verification in an Ecommerce site

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart, coupon

Hi all I am implementing a coupon code verification option in my Ecommerce website. I have two types of coupons either flat amount or percentage. How to tackle both of these in backend. I mean in database schema.

Comment: Let's say you got `coupons` table. Along with other fields (keys, descriptions and so on) add `coupon_type` as `ENUM('percentage','amount')` and `coupon_value` as `decimal(12,2)` (or shorter). In `coupon_value` hold literal value (0.XX for XX%) and later in code just add or multiple - depends on `coupon_type`.

Comment: For answers that have been posted - **never** keep prices as floats - these are exact values and keeping them as floats will cause you problems later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CouponTypeTBL
id type
1  flat
2  percent

CouponTBL
id  typeid  uniquecode  amount   validfromdate   validtodate  useddate  status etc...
1   1       a1-xx       100.00   ....
2   2       cvd11       7.5      ...
```

So you have here a coupon:

> **a1-xx** which is a flat amount of 100

and

> **cvd11** which gives a 7.5% discount.

You can make this model more complex, which currency, if flat will there be an amount left if used under the fixed amount etc .. etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table that has

**CUPON CODE, PERCENT, AMOUNT, USABLE_COUNT**

this way you can have cupons that do both (if someone would want that).

**USABLE_COUNT** for cupons that can be used only a certain number of times.

But there are a lot of other features that you might consider, like minimum pourchase amount for a cupon.

Answer (score 0):

**percentage** = integer (1%, 10%, 100%, etc.) or double/float (1.11% 10.1%, 99.999%, etc.)

**flat amount** = integer (1, 10, 100, etc.) or double/float (1.11, 10.1, 99.999, etc.)

Save it in backend as integer or as double/float/decimal...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coupon` (
    `code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `amount` float NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
);
```

Easy example...

Answer (score 0):

put both amount and percentage as suppurate columns. otherwise if put both percentage and amount in singe column by giving a discriminator column that will coz a problem if you want to provide a domain to either amt r percent eg: more then 100% is not allowed as discount or min 10 rs shold be given as discount.